# How to update Kubernetes Dashboard in hosted Kubernetes on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using the hosted version of Kubernetes inside Google Container Engine (GKE).

Currently we are at Version 1.3.x, which comes with an Kubernetes Dashboard v1.1.1.

Some days ago Kubernetes Dashboard v1.4.0 was released which includes some very nice enhancements.

My **Question**: **What is the recommended way to update the Kubernetes Dashboard** on a hosted (**GKE**) Kubernetes cluster?

The cluster comes with a Dashboard controlled by an Replication Controller. We could just dump the RC config, edit the image tag and labels and apply it. But I don't want to break the dashboard. So I'd like to know what the "official" or suggested way of doing this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official way is to update your cluster to 1.4. It should be available a few days after Kubernetes 1.4 is released. You can do this via gcloud CLI or Google Cloud Console (click "Upgrade available" next to your cluster).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  I'm on 1.5.6 in GKE and dashboard is still at 1.5.0.  Git repo shows tags for 1.5.1 and 1.6.0.

Comment: When you'll be on 1.6 on GKE, the Dashboard will also be updated to 1.6. Only major version versions of core and Dashboard are in sync.

Comment: cool, thanks.  Sorry for the downvote, it got stuck.  I upvoted you somewhere else :-)

Answer (score 1):

GKE didn't manage this during upgrades on my clusters.  Reinstall from kubernetes git repo:

☀  kubectl apply -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml